# @JsonFormat pattern for LocalTime

Tags: java, serialization, java-8, jackson, localtime

I have this field

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
private Date completionDate;
```

I get this result: `2021-10-05T14:17:16Z`

I need to split this date into 2 fields:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate date;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ???)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalTime time;
```

I know what I should use in the date part. But what pattern is needed for the time part? `"HH:mm:ss'Z'"`?

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Do not mix the legacy and the modern Date-Time API:** In your code, you have mixed the error-prone legacy Date-Time API with the modern Date-Time API which will make your code unnecessarily complex and error-prone. I recommend you declare `completionDate` as `ZonedDateTime` from which you can retrieve the Date and Time parts as shown in the following example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime completionDate = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        LocalDate date = completionDate.toLocalDate();
        LocalTime time = completionDate.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(completionDate);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(time);

        // Some examples of custom formats
        DateTimeFormatter dtfTime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(time.format(dtfTime));

        DateTimeFormatter dtfDtTz = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(completionDate.format(dtfDtTz));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-10-06T08:56:37.131679Z[Etc/UTC]
2021-10-06
08:56:37.131679
08:56:37
2021-10-06T08:56:37Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/YuII2q)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>